# Is there a SQL Server way to take 1-1000 rows of broken-up binary file data and append them all into one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The original implementation of the SQL Server database I am working on broke database binary file uploads into 1MB chunks and wrote them to the database with a shared identifier. I have been tasked with writing a migration that will take all of these pieces of data and merge them into one row per file upload.

This has left me with a couple questions:

1. Is there a reason to keep file uploads broken into 1MB chunks?
2. Is `varchar(max)` (the current column type) the right column type for file uploads (both for 1MB chunks and full one-row file storage)? It seems like that is roughly 2GB of potential storage. Our software allows a maximum file size of 1GB, so that would technically be enough storage for one-row entries. I have been reading about TEXT and BLOB column types for file storage, but most posts / articles that talk about these are 6-9 years old at this point.

Comment: That was a typo. I actually am using MSSQL, not MYSQL

Comment: If you want to store binary files, you should use a **binary** datatype - like `varbinary(max)` - not a string-based type like `varchar` .....

Comment: Are the files text files, or binary?

Comment: I think the best option for storing binary data in SQL server is the type `[varbinary](max) FILESTREAM` You will than be able to both read and write data to the table using a stream (just like for files)

Comment: @TabAlleman - These are binary

Comment: I guess the main question I have is why are you storing binary data in a SQL Server database.  Databases are good at storing and retrieving relatively small amounts of data.  In relational calculus, this is called a tuple.  In my experience, storing binary results in the data in a overflow page and slows things down.  IMOO - A better solution is to store a path to the binary file and save it on disk.

Comment: I have looked over many db-vs-file-system argument articles and seen the pros and cons for both sides.